# mismatched python version on windows machine

Tags: python, windows, environment-variables

I am facing a very strange problem with my windows machine

I have only Python 3.6 installed on my machine

but every time I try to run my project I get the following message

```
Failed to load paths: No Python at 'C:\Users\amira\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe'
```

I do not have version 310 in my machine, the folder specified does not have Python10 Folder

I also checked Environment Variable and make sure only Python36 is found

how can I solve this strange problem please?

[image]

Comment: How are you running your project, which command(s) are you executing?

Comment: pipenv install --deploy

Comment: It can so happen that some version of python can get left out in AppData folder, you can simply delete that folder, and also any references to that path in your PATH env variables, since you have already checked, the only other place to check is Registry, check by searching for 'AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310' in RegEdit.

Comment: Check these 3 registry paths to start with , HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Python\, 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Python, and HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Python.

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran I did all that you suggest, actually, I do not only delete the keys that you suggest, I even search in all registries for any value equal to the path specified and delete them all, but the problem still found, do you have any other solution please ?

Comment: Check the `path` variable; run `echo [%path:;=]&echo.[%]` for better readability.